# IBM Watson Assistant for non-English language - Intent is not recognized

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am working with IBM Watson Asistant for Korean and found the failure rate to detect the correct intent is so high. Therefore, I decided to check language support and I can see the [important missing features](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-language-support) that is [Entity Fuzzy Matching](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-entities#entities-fuzzy-matching):

> Partial match - With partial matching, the feature automatically suggests substring-based synonyms present in the user-defined entities, and assigns a lower confidence score as compared to the exact entity match.

This result in the chatbot that is not very intelligent for which we need to provide synonyms **for each word**.  Check out the example below where Watson Assistant in English can detect an intent from words that is not included in the example by any means. I tested and found it is not possible for Korean language to do so.

I wonder If I understood something wrong or there is away to workaround this issue that I do not know of?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you start with IBM Watson Assistant and an untrained dialog. You can significantly improve the understood intents and entities by providing more examples and then [using the dashboard to tag correctly understood conversations and to change incorrect intents / entities to the right ones](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-logs#logs-correct-intent). This is the preferred way and is just part of the regular development process which includes training the model.

Another method, this time as workaround, is to preprocess a dialog using [Watson Natural Language Understanding which has Korean support, too](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/natural-language-understanding?topic=natural-language-understanding-language-support#korean).

BTW: I use German language for some of my bots and it requires training for some scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Henrik's answer, here are couple of tips while creating an intent

1. Provide at least **five** examples for each intent.
2. Always re-train your system

> If the system does not recognize the correct intent, you can correct
> it. To correct the recognized intent, select the displayed intent and
> then select the correct intent from the list. After your correction is
> submitted, the system automatically retrains itself to incorporate the
> new data.

3. Remember, The Watson Assistant service scores each intent’s confidence independently, not in relation to other intents.
4. Avoid conflicts and if there are any [resolve the conflicts](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-intents#intents-resolve-conflicts) - The Watson Assistant application detects a conflict when two or more intent examples in separate intents are so similar that Watson Assistant is confused as to which intent to use.